# Excel conditional formatting - highlight cell if two conditions are met

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two tables of data and want to use conditional formatting to highlight certain cells in the first table if they meet two criteria. The first table shows a schedule of matches to be played in the following form:

`A       B       C         Z
1  TEAM  | WEEK1 | WEEK2 ... WEEK25
2  TEAM1 | TEAM5 | TEAM9 ... TEAM2
3  TEAM2 | TEAM2 | TEAM3 ... TEAM1
...
10 TEAM9 | TEAM4 | TEAM1 ... TEAM8`

i.e: Team 1 plays Team 5, then Team 9, etc before finishing with Team 2

The second table shows the top 5 and bottom 5 teams for defensive and attacking ability:

`AA      AB      AC      AD
1 BESTA | BESTD | WORSTA| WORSTD
2 TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx 
3 TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx 
4 TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx 
5 TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx 
6 TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx | TEAMx`

This table is updated automatically from data elsewhere.

What I want to do is conditionally format the match schedule to highlight matches between the best attacking teams and worst defensive teams. I am trying things like this:

```
=AND(IF($A2=ISTEXT($AA$2:$AA$6)),IF($B$2:$Z$2=ISTEXT($AD$2:$AD$6)))
```

In other words, highlight if the first column value appears in the BESTA list and any opponent from the schedule appears in the WORSTD list. Then I would copy the formatting over all rows of the schedule. However, this returns an error and I can't work out what to change to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your formula is all wrong (eg try it in a cell rather than as a CF rule) and I think there are several possibilities you have not covered, but a CF rule applied to A2:Z10 of:

```
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($A2,$AA$2:$AA$6,0))),NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$AD$2:$AD$6,0))))
```

with formatting of your choice should highlight those teams in columnsB:Z that are listed in ColumnAD when the team in ColumnA is listed in ColumnAA.

Comment: Yes my syntax was wrong but it was just my way of trying to show you what I meant in pseudo code. Thank you for this suggestion, I will try it out.